# Need help with tree diagram / formula for a probability question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a problem here that I am trying to solve. Event A may take place either due to E1 or E2. The probability of E1 happening is .3, whereas the probability of E2 happening is .2. Also, the likelihood of E2 happening is increased to .3 if E1 occurs. I need to calculate the probability that A happens. I made a tree diagram and calculated the probability, but it doesn't tally with the answer I got from using the formula that relates union and intersection of probabilities.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzpLy.png)

Comment: "*The probability of E2 happening is .2... Also the likelihood of E2 happening is increased to .3 if E1 occurs*"  These two pieces of information together imply that the likelihood of E2 happening if E1 does not occur will *not* be .2 but will rather be less to compensate for the increase.  You incorrectly used the value of 0.2 there in your method1.

Comment: Your method2 is correct.

Comment: Thanks JMoravitz. Can I use a tree diagram to represent this problem? Or is the formula the only way?

Comment: You can, but you would need to first find $\Pr(E_2\mid \neg E_1)$ noting that $\Pr(E_2) = \Pr(E_2\mid E_1)\Pr(E_1)+\Pr(E_2\mid \neg E_1)\Pr(\neg E_1)$... but once you get that far deep in formulas, you might as well have taken a more direct approach to begin with

Comment: You would have gotten $(0.2-0.09)/0.7\approx 0.157\dots$ as the probability of $E_2$ happening given that $E_1$ did not happen.

Comment: Thanks again JMoravitz. But can you explain the formula for Pr(E2 |¬E1)? I am afraid I don't get it.

Comment: We have a formula for $\Pr(E_2)$ as per the Law of Total Probability, that $\Pr(E_2)=\Pr(E_2\cap E_1)+\Pr(E_2\cap E_1^c)$, and these intersections can expand by definition of conditional probability as I had in the comment above.  We have all of the pieces of information in that expression with the exception of $\Pr(E_2\mid E_1^c)$.  Rearranging to isolate that gives the above.

Comment: All clear. Thank you very much.